# Elasticsearch Installation for magento 2.4.0 on centos 7

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I am trying to install magento 2.4.0,but I am stuck at the point of installing and starting elasticsearch. It always says "Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details" when I start elasticsearch. What could be the cause and the possible solution